# Take an attribute from a list of pojo class to an array of that attribute

Tags: java

Suppose for one field/attribute in a pojo class , i need to create a list of that field's value alone. Its doable in java using iteration . But is there any custom library for doing this ?
For eg :

```
public class User
{
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  // setters and getters. 
}
```

What i want is , `List<User>` ---> `List<String>` , here the values are of field "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can create a stream from the list and apply a mapping function to map it to a list of names:

```
List<User> users;
List<String> names = users.stream().map(user -> user.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. Any solution in Java 7 ?

Comment: @Mohammedshebin You can use Google's Guava project. It allows for transforming a list via a function.